# Navigating between Views using Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following problem:

My app has 3 views, between the first and the second is necessary to use Navigation Controller but the third is not necessary, the occult with `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: YES];` and return to the second mendiante a button and segue.

My problem is that when you return to the second view, it appears as navigation controller, but when you press back, it goes to the third view and not the first as it should. Can you help?

Comment: Not sure what "mendiante" means? Can you use another word?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how (and where) you have added `UINavigationController`? Also, I don't understand "return to the second mendiante a button and segue". Are you French?

Comment: "mediante"=using a button and segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use "push segue" from third view to second view.
Use

```
- (IBAction)backToPreviousView:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

for third view button touch up event instead.
Here is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJv03.png) for your preview.